# Label or div won't show on javaScript check box change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm building a page using ASP.NET web forms, with JavaScript and jQuery.
What I'm trying to do is to make check box that reacts on check box change event like this: if check box is selected: show 3 labels on screen, else check box is deselected: open modal pop up.

I've manage to make pop up window working as properly, but my labels never seem to show on screen. I've tried accessing them throughout div element, and I've tried to access single label, but still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/BankInformation.ascx" TagName="BankInformation" TagPrefix="ABS" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isDirectDebitSelected = $('#<%=chkDirectDebit.ClientID%>');
        var sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox = $('#<%=chkSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>');
        var sameAsMerchantBankLabel = $('#<%=txtSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>');
        var bankInformation = $('#<%=bankInfoDialog.ClientID%>');
        var accountInfo = $('#<%=divAccountInfo.ClientID%>');
        var ibanLabel = $('<%=lblIBAN.ClientID%>');

        function OpenDirectDebitDialog(dialogID) {
            dialogID.modal();
        }

        function ValidateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog(validationGroup, dialogID) {
            var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
            if (pageValid)
                $(dialogID).modal("hide");
        }

        $(sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox).change(function () {
            if (sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
                accountInfo.show();
                ibanLabel.show();
            } else {
                OpenDirectDebitDialog(bankInformation);
            }    
        });

        function setSameAsMerchantVisible() {
            if (isDirectDebitSelected.is(':checked')) {
                sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox.show();
                sameAsMerchantBankLabel.show();
            } else {
                sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox.hide();
                sameAsMerchantBankLabel.hide();
            }
        }
        isDirectDebitSelected.bind('change', function () {
            setSameAsMerchantVisible();
        });

        setSameAsMerchantVisible();
    });
</script>

<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkDirectDebit" />
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkSameAsMerchantBank" ID="txtDirectDebit" meta:resourcekey="lblDirectDebit"></asp:Label>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSameAsMerchantBank" AutoPostBack="False" Checked="True" />
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtSameAsMerchantBank" ID="txtSameAsMerchantBank" meta:resourcekey="lblSameAsMerchantBank"></asp:Label>

<div id="bankInfoDialog" runat="server" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h1 id="bankInformationDialogHeader"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("BankInfoHeader") %></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ABS:BankInformation runat="server" ID="bankInformation" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" meta:resourcekey="btnUpdate" />
        <button id="btnCancel" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Cancel")%></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divAccountInfo" style="visibility: hidden" runat="server">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIBAN" meta:resourcekey="lblIBAN"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAccountNumber" meta:resourcekey="lblAccountNumber"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSwiftNumber" meta:resourcekey="lblSwiftNumber"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Check box Set same as merchant bank is hidden before Direct debit check box is checked. Could that cause that labels aren't showed?
Event gets fired for sure, since modal pop up is shown.

Comment: Do `$(divAccountInfo).css('visibility', 'visible');` for your `div`

Comment: As you have not done `display:none` `.show()` not works.

Comment: change `$(sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox).change` with `sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox.change` because this is already a `jquery` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's show/hide methods work via "display". Replace "visibility: hidden" with "display: none" and it will work as expected.

```
 <div id="divAccountInfo" style="display: none" runat="server">
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIBAN" meta:resourcekey="lblIBAN"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAccountNumber" meta:resourcekey="lblAccountNumber"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSwiftNumber" meta:resourcekey="lblSwiftNumber"></asp:Label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for making my comment as answer.